# Webpage s loading slow after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have some timming issue with my web site
Each time i try to access The response.php page from my site i wait over 40 sec.
All website is gzipped. headers and files have a big expiry date.
The response.php has The php size has a SOAP connection, a SQL interogation
The php side has a 12-14 sec load time
The HTML/JS side of the response page is loading within 10 sec

My issue is when i try to access this page before showing the preloader it takes a lot of time arround 20 sec. I see waiting for www....mysite.com
I have a VPS with CEONTOS: 6 GB RAM, 6 CPU`s and 60 GB SSD
Let me know if you need the link to my page.

How can i find the root cause of this?

Comment: one of the optimization,  use proper index for table columns...

Answer (score 1):

@CARASS This kind of slowness because of SOAP response, try reducing the default_socket_timeout to 10 seconds(Normally it will take 60 seconds) and check the page. If you are still getting the pages slowly, please check with the service provider for service call.

Comment: the page still stay 10 to 15 sec for the preloader to shown up

Comment: @CARASS, Please check the code with Debugger like **XDebug** and check where exactly the slowness is happening